# How to zoom image and stop it for 2 sec in splash Screen

Tags: java, android

I have problem with stop imageview for few sec in splash screen with zoom animation . I try to do a add xml zoom2 and tak scale from 1.0 to 1.0 with duration 2000 , but in splash.java i dont know how to add this in good way .

Please help me :)

zoom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<scale
android:duration="1500"
android:fromXScale="0.0"
android:fromYScale="0.0"
android:pivotX="50%p"
android:pivotY=50p"
android:toXScale="1.0"
android:toYScale="1.0">
</scale>
</set>
```

Splash.java

```
package com.example.maciek.polskieinternety;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Created by Maciek on 12.05.2016.
 */
public class Splash extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashh);


        final ImageView zoom = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        final Animation zoomAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.zoom);
        zoom.startAnimation(zoomAnimation);
        zoomAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                finish();
                Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following code in your

> onAnimationEnd()

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
    Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
        public void run() {
             finish();
            Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    };
mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 2000);
```

Comment: THX , This Help :) im beginer and its so helpfull for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a handler with postDelayed in your OnAnimationEnd.